# Convert JSON (not generated by AVRO) to Avro Specific Record

Tags: java, json, avro, avro-tools

I have a use case to convert the JSON data to an Avro-specific record. When I say JSON it is plain JSON (not generated by Avro to have type information). I have the Avro Schema and its generated class.

When I try to convert the using Avro utility, I get the following exception,

```
Expected start-union. Got VALUE_NUMBER_INT
```

The Avro utility works well if the JSON is generated by the Avro library because it adds the type and union information to it. But, in my use case, I have a plain JSON without type information generated by another service.

After long research, I found the open issue in JIRA - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1582

The above issue is about generic use case, but, I have the schema and its generated class, so is there any option to convert the JSON to Avro Specific records when I have the schema using Java?

Comment: [JsonDecoder](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/io/JsonDecoder.html) is intended for reading [Avro's JSON encoding](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding). It is not a general purpose JSON parser.

Comment: Right, that's what my understanding, is there any solution for my use case?

Comment: Use a JSON library such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) to deserialize JSON to Java objects.

Comment: Right it works, but, it fails when the field name contains "_", because the Java generated class removes the underscore in the getters/setters. One of the solution is to specify using addMixIn and override the setters/getters, but this looks hacky. Is there any option/configuration to avoid the renaming of the fields in the getter/setters while generating the Avro record class?

Comment: If Jackson's ObjectMapper property naming strategy is set to PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE, then Jackson converts JSON property names composed of lowercase words separated by underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json-avro-converter library](https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter). It decodes plain jsons without additional type information.